# Place canonical on my website

Tags: seo, canonical-url

I have list of movies on my website, and I have filters like sort by "category" or "duration" or "rated".
I learned in this situation on all this filter I need do add:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />
```

because this is all same content just show on other order,
my question, if I add `canonical` on `example.com/filter?=rate`
then I add:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />
```

or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com/filter?=rate" />
```

[image: Screenshot of webpage, showing a table with select lists 'Category', 'Duration', and 'Sort by']

Comment: Canonical tags are designed to point to the original content and not itself.

Comment: Is `filter` really part of the URL-path? And _only_ serves to filter the results?

Comment: filter just show URL-s from front page on other order, you think in this case i need use `canonical` ? @closetnoc in this case i in source code in each filter add `<link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `http://example.com/filter` shows the list with *all* movies, and `http://example.com/filter?=rate` shows the list with all these entries sorted differently, then it’s appropriate to use the [`canonical` link type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596).

So on `http://example.com/filter?=rate` you could add:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/filter" />
```

However, if you want the list that is sorted by rating to be the canonical one, you could add on `http://example.com/filter`:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/filter?=rate" />
```

(But in that case you might want to change the URL, so that `/filter` is sorted by rating by default.)

If the filters "Category" and "Duration" also generate new URLs, and if they never show more movies than listed in the "default" (canonical) list, you can point from the filtered pages to the `canonical` URL, too.

Comment: if i add `canonical` on some pages, google will completly ignore this pages and not indexed nothing from there or ?

Comment: @nikola99: If you use `canonical` correctly (i.e., only for pages that are identical or a superset), it’s likely that Google Search will only show your canonical page (the duplicates might still get indexed, e.g., for `site:` or `cache:` searches; but I don’t know if Google does this). -- Note that `canonical` is only an advice, it’s not a requirement for Google or any other consumer to follow this advice (robots.txt / `meta`-`robots` could be considered requirements, to control crawling/indexing).